# Magento 2.3 show Block only when customer not logged in

Tags: magento2.3, layout, custom-block

I need to show a Block on my product detail page when the customer **is not logged** in only.
What is the best way to achieve that in Magento 2.3?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you use custom Module file ? share your block and phtml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following code in your block file Eg:CustomBlock.php

```
<?php
namespace [vendor_name]\[module_name]\Block;
class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
  public function isCustomerLoggedIn()
  {
    $customer = $this->customerSession->create();
        if(!($customer->isLoggedIn()))
             return true;
        return false;
  }    
}
```

?>

and kindly add the following code in your template file

```
<?php
$checkCustomer = $block->isCustomerLoggedIn();
if($checkCustomer):
   echo "<b>Please Login!! </b>";
endif;
?>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks that is working :-)!

Comment: Welcome!! :) @schotti

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick and dirty way that works (tested in 2.4.3-pl), but it uses ObjectManager which is not recommended as best practice.
Just stick this in the .phtml file you want it to work in.

```
<?php
$checkCustomer = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::class);

if($checkCustomer->isLoggedIn()) {
    //DO YOUR THANG HERE
}
?>
```

Personally, I don't fully understand why doing it like this is "bad" (perhaps someone could enlighten me below), but obviously it's up to the developer how they achieve what they're on a deadline to achieve.